# How do I load variables from a file back into Scala?

Tags: scala, file-io, input, java-io

I have variables in scala that have their values written to an external file in this format:

```
1
2
0
0.5
0.62
```

This is my code that puts them in the file called "myVars.txt":

```
  val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter("myVars.txt")
  pw.println(beginGameCounter)
  pw.println(triangleCount)
  pw.println(triangleScore)
  pw.println(lives)
  pw.println(curPlayer.getX)
  pw.println(curPlayer.getY)
  pw.close
```

How would I load these variables back into scala and replace the old variables with these new variables (for example the old variable for beginGameCounter is 0, then when I load the file, I want it to become 1)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
  val values = Source.fromFile(pathToFile).getLines.toList
  beginGameCounter = values(0)
  triangleCount = values(1)
  triangleScore = values(2)
  lives = values(3)
  currPlayer.setX(values(4))
  currPlayer.setY(values(5))
```

This of course assumes that the what variable is on what line is consistent.

Comment: Awesome - this worked, except I had to add .toInt or .toDouble after each value like this but it works: 
    values(0).toInt

Comment: Ya, I wasn't sure what types your different vars were, so I figured this would be enough for you to get it working all the way.